# Execute excel formula stored in a string from a macro

Tags: excel, vba

Requirement:
Calculate the number of Mondays that are holidays between a date range and execute them using a macro.
I could arrive at he formula that can give me the correct result

```
 =SumProduct((VIC >= DATEVALUE("1/01/2016")) * (VIC <= DATEVALUE("19/01''/2018")) * (Weekday(VIC, 2) = 1))
```

Can you please help me execute the formula stored in string?

```
Sub TestFunction()
    Dim LeaveStartDate, LeaveEndDate As Date

    Set srcdoc = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim CntSunPH  As String

    LeaveStartDate = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, "B").Value
    LeaveEndDate = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, "B").Value

    State = "VIC"
    CntSunPH = Replace((Replace(Replace(("=SumProduct((State >= DATEVALUE(""LeaveStartDate"")) * (State <= DATEVALUE(""LeaveEndDate"")) * (Weekday(State, 2) = 1))"), "State", State), "LeaveStartDate", LeaveStartDate)), "LeaveEndDate", LeaveEndDate)
    n = 0
    n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Execute("=SumProduct((VIC >= DATEVALUE(""1/01/2016"")) * (VIC <= DATEVALUE(""19/01/2018"")) * (Weekday(VIC, 2) = 1))")

    Debug.Print "Date1 " & LeaveStartDate
    Debug.Print "Date2  " & LeaveEndDate
    Debug.Print CntSunPH

    Debug.Print n    
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that `Dim LeaveStartDate, LeaveEndDate As Date` only declares the second as `Date` but the first as `Variant`. You need to declare a type for **every** variable: `Dim LeaveStartDate As Date, LeaveEndDate As Date`. • Do you get any errors? If so please include in your question where and which. It's unclear where exactly your issue is. Also have a look at the [Worksheet.Evaluate method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.Evaluate).

Comment: Is there a typo in your formula or are the quotes/apostrophes before the second `/` in `DATEVALUE("19/01''/2018"))` meant to be there?